# Best Practise for building mobile site

Tags: api, rest, web-applications, mobile, scaling

I am about to start building a mobile site which is dynamic, working from a lot of dynamic content which must come from the database.

I have already written a REST API for the site which the IOS and Android applications are using to interact with the information.

My question is what would be the absolute best practise for building this site, would it be:

**1- Make the mobile classes an extension of the existing site functions**

(The downside I see here is that the mobile site would be dependant on the main site library meaning that any bad heat on the main site would also affect the mobile site)

**2- Make the mobile site a completely stand alone site running from itself**

(The downside I see here is that any change to the main site library will need to be reflected here so in essence we would almost be writing code twice)

**3- Make the mobile site run from the REST API and standalone**

(The downside i see here is just increased number of HTTP requests for the information rather than communicating with the server directly)

Each one would function normally and there wouldn't really be any problem there, coding is really not too difficult, though if I make it standalone I would need to recreate a lot of the functions from the main site and adapt them for the mobile site which isn't ideal.

Look forward to your comments! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would go with 3rd point, but that needs to be architect well.

We will prioritize standalone  application after that API, also we can have 2 way communication, any content changed on server it will coordinate with  clients to get that updated.

Also I would also suggest go with Bootstrap framework, its an awesome framework and have responsive and adaptive design